Forward information between two classes with a buffer in between
I am trying to set up a buffer where a class fills it, and another class creates and reads the data and removes the nodes.
EDIT: I removed the examples and added my actual code. Maybe that is easier to understand than my previous example and makes more sense to troubleshoot. I had to shorten it but here the important parts.
EDIT2:
I removed my examples and added a new file so its less confusing.
So class processData creates a buffer from the template. Class readSensor should get the address of the buffer and also be able to write data in it (uses writeToBuffer() from template). And class processData read the data back from it and deletes the node afterwards.
Old:
within the same class, everything works but am not able to read from the buffer from the second class. The buffer is in its own file and included in both files containing the classes.
I tried many different ways, but nothing worked so far, and I start from scratch now.
NEW:
It seems I always created a new instance of processData and so a new buffer which of course has a different pointer address. Here it uses a pointer to an instance (that already exists) instead of creating a new one.
I also tried to find a better way to run both instances in separate threads but not sure if there is a smarter solution to manage that.
testfile
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

#include "buffer.hpp"


std::mutex bufferMutex;


struct TEST_DATA
{
double val_a;
double val_b;
double val_c;
};


class processData
{
public:
processData() {}
~processData() {}

CircularBuffer<TEST_DATA>& getTESTBuffer() { return test_buffer; 
}

void start()
{
    create();
    read();
}

void create()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(bufferMutex);
    std::cout << "\nCreate buffer";
    test_buffer.createBuffer();
    printf("\nFrom processData: ");
    std::cout << "\nAddress of test_buffer: " << &test_buffer << std::endl;
}

void read()
{
    printf("\nFrom processData: ");
    TEST_DATA read_data;
    std::cout << "\nPM: Trying to read from Buffer\n";
    for(;;)
    { 
        while (test_buffer.readFromBuffer(read_data))
            std::cout << "Val a: " << read_data.val_a << " Val b: " << read_data.val_b << std::endl;
    }
}

private:
CircularBuffer<TEST_DATA> test_buffer;
 };



class readSensor
{
public:
readSensor(processData& sensor, std::mutex& mutex) : sensor(sensor), bufferMutex(mutex) {}
~readSensor() {}

void start()
{
    printf("\nFrom readSensor: before mutex, wait... ");
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(bufferMutex);
    printf("\nFrom readSensor: ");
    CircularBuffer<TEST_DATA>& bufferRef = sensor.getTESTBuffer();
    std::cout << "\nAddress of the buffer: " << &bufferRef << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Write to buffer" << std::endl;
    TEST_DATA test_data1;
    test_data1.val_a = 1234;
    test_data1.val_b = 9876;
    bufferRef.writeToBuffer(test_data1);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    TEST_DATA test_data2;
    test_data2.val_a = 9999;
    test_data2.val_b = 8888;
    bufferRef.writeToBuffer(test_data2);
}

private:
processData& sensor;
std::mutex& bufferMutex;

};



int main()
{
processData sensor;
readSensor reader(sensor, bufferMutex);

std::thread processData_thread([&sensor]() { sensor.start(); });
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
std::thread readSensor_thread([&reader]() { reader.start(); });

readSensor_thread.join();
processData_thread.join();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

buffer.hpp
#ifndef BUFFER_HPP_INCLUDED
#define BUFFER_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
struct CircularNode
{
T data;
CircularNode* next;
};

template<typename T>
class CircularBuffer
{
public:
CircularBuffer() : head(NULL), tail(NULL), buffer_created(false),     
node_count(0) {}
~CircularBuffer() {}

bool createBuffer()
{
    if (buffer_created)
        return false;
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    buffer_created = true;
    node_count = 0;
    return true;
}

bool writeToBuffer(const T& data)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(buffer_mutex);
    if (!buffer_created)
        return false;
    try
    {
        CircularNode<T>* new_node = new CircularNode<T>{ data, 
   nullptr };
        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
            new_node->next = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
            tail->next = head;
        }
        ++node_count;
        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc& e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool readFromBuffer(T& out_data)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(buffer_mutex);

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        out_data = head->data;
        CircularNode<T>* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        if (head == temp)
        {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }
        else
            tail->next = head;
        delete temp;
        --node_count;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private:
CircularNode<T>* head;
CircularNode<T>* tail;
mutable std::mutex buffer_mutex;
bool buffer_created;
std::string buffer_name;
size_t node_count;
};

#endif


Do you get any error? If yes, kindly post the complete error.

We need a [mcve]. Something that we can copy/paste into a compiler and reproduce the issue.

The examples are strange too. No constructors, the methods in calc and sensor are private, the variable is public. There is also no workflow between them described in the post (only the buffer seems to somehow magically be shared). Please explain what " but am not able to read from the buffer from the second class" means. Do you get errors? is the data incomplete, invalid or incorrect? Have you attempted to debug it? What are the results?

class sensor
{
private:
    CircularBuffer<STRUCTURE> sensor1_buffer;

The sensor class has a CircularBuffer, and writes data into it.
class calc
{
public:
    CircularBuffer<STRUCTURE> sensor1_buffer;

The calc class has a CircularBuffer, and tries to read data from it.
But there's absolutely no connection between these two entirely separate CircularBuffers.
Here's an analogy.  I have a mouth. My cat has a mouth. But when I eat food, the cat doesn't get full.
What you probably want is for one or both classes to have either a reference or a pointer to a CircularBuffer that is not part of the class.
class calc
{
public:
    CircularBuffer<STRUCTURE>* sensor1_buffer; //pointer
   ...
}
int main() {
   sensor thingSensor;
   calc calculation;

   //make the calculation's sensor1_buffer member *point at* the sensor's buffer.
   calculation.sensor1_buffer = &thingSensor.sensor1_buffer; 

Alternatively, make a CircularBuffer externally, and then make the calc and sensor both point at it. Whichever makes more sense.

"Variations" of this would be one class having the queue internally, and offering a public "push" call for other modules to add jobs to it. This would generally be useful if it's not such a strict A<->B relation.
